# how to Deploy my repository in bitbucket to AWS with CodeDeploy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, bitbucket, aws-code-deploy, bitbucket-aws-code-deploy

I have a repository in bitbucket. now I want to deploy it to my aws EC2 instance using amazon code-deploy.how can I do that? what steps should I follow?

Comment: I don`t understand why all the negative feedbacks?

Comment: You should first do some research, google `bitbucket aws codedeploy` for example and see what comes up. And then if you still have doubts come here and ask for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **AWS code-pipeline** to take source code from the bitbucket and If you want build it, you can build using the code-build and then deploy it using the code-deploy.
Follow this link for more details:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/tutorials-simple-codecommit.html